# Can jQuery.css() ignore CSS transition?

Tags: jquery, cross-browser, css-transitions

This is about a cross-browser issue. On Chrome and Safari, the following HTML has different behaviors. On chrome and firefox, the text will be '40px', while on Safari, '0px'.

I know why they behave differently. In regards of the CSS transition, on chrome, if the starting value is 'auto', it will not trigger the transition, and .css() immediately sets the `left` value; while in Safari, starting value being auto won't prevent the transition, so the value will transit to '40px' during 1 second, at the very first moment, its value is '0'.

This discrepancy of behavior has affected my program. I want the CSS value to be set immediately on all browsers, instead of being transit. Does jQuery offer such kind of function that sets CSS value immediately ignoring CSS transition?

And, if no, what is the best way to overcome this browser behavioral discrepancy?

Fiddel: http://jsfiddle.net/ajLxgcn7/2/

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var s = $('.a').css('left',40).css('left');
            $('.a').html(s);
        });
        </script>

        <style>
        .container {
            position:relative;
            width:300px;
            height:300px;
            background-color:yellow;
            padding:20px
        }
        .a {
            padding:40px;
            position:absolute;
            background-color:red;
            width:100px;
            height:100px;
            color:black;
            left:auto;
            transition:all 1s ease
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='container'>
        <div class='a'></div>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to put the type of value

```
$('.a').css('left', '40px');
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/css/ When a number is passed as the value, jQuery will convert it to a string and add px to the end of that string.